# conditional JSON transformation in JOLT

Tags: json, jolt

I need to process response from SOLR service that looks like following:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "distanceUnits": "mi", //it can be "mi", "MI", "miles", "km", "KM", etc.
    "solrResponse": {
      "header": {
        "found": 32,
        "retrieved": 10,
        ... //there can be other things like timestamp
      },
      "results": [
        {
          "matchScore": "08768",
          "indicators" [{...}],
          "location": {
             ... //there are about hundred attributes
            "distance": "2.7649" //distance always in km
            "similarity": "0.342"
        },
        ...
      ]
}
```

The transformation need to return everything from solrResponse practically intact except two things:

1. similarity need to be renamed to similarityScore and moved up next to matchScore.
2. If distanceUnit is specified as miles, distance need to be converted to miles (i.e. divided by 1.609)
3. distance value is to berounded to 2 digits after decimal point and concatenated with distanceUnit.
   I have created the following spec:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "unit1": "=toLower(@(1,distanceUnit))",
        "unit2": "=substring(@(1,unit1),0,1)",
        "solrResponse": {
          "results": {
            "": {
              "dist1": "=divideAndRound(2,@(1,distance),0.6215)",
              "distanceMiles": "=concat(@(1,dist1), ' ', @(2,distanceUnit))",
              "dist2": "=divideAndRound(2,@(1,distance),1.0)",
              "distanceKm": "=concat(@(1,dist2), ' ', @(2,distanceUnit))"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "solrResponse": {
          "header": "&1",
          "response": {
            "": {
              "&1.similarity": "similarityScore",
              "unit2": {
                "m": {
                  "distanceMiles": "locations.distance"
                },
                "": {
                  "distanceKm": "locations.distance"
                }
              },
              "": "&1"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Unfortunately it does not work. Please help me.

Comment: For the second matter; do you mean : *"...need to be converted to **kilometers** (i.e. **multiplied** by 1.609)"* ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Jolt doesn't have a function such as `multiply` or `product`, but `divide` and `divideAndRound` to be used in a **modify** transformation spec. Then, we'll have a conditional to filer out whether the provided value for `distanceUnit` attribute exists within the list(`mi,m,Mi,MI`) or not such as

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "*": { // this outer one represents "locations" list(if there's no other outer level list or object, otherwise replace "*" with the key name "locations") 
        "*": { // this one stands for "locations" list's indexes
          "distanceinMiles_": "=divideAndRound(2,@(1,distance),0.6215040397762585)",
          "distanceinMiles": "=concat(@(1,distanceinMiles_),' ',@(1,distanceUnit))",
          "distance_": "=divideAndRound(2,@(1,distance),1)",
          "distance": "=concat(@(1,distance_),' ',@(1,distanceUnit))"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": {
          "address": "&2[&1].&",
          "city": "&2[&1].&",
          "state": "&2[&1].&",
          "postalCode": "&2[&1].&",
          "distanceUnit": {
            "mi|m|Mi|MI": { "@(2,distanceinMiles)": "&4[&3].distance" },
            "*": { "@(2,distance)": "&4[&3].distance" }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

where

- **`@(1,distanceXx)`** in the first spec represents traversing one colon(**`:`**) (as a Right-Hand-Side element) in order to reach the
  original level of the elements **`@(1,distanceXx)`**, while
  **`@(2,distanceXx)`** stands for traversing **`{`** (object opening "curly" brace) twice to reach the same.
- the attributes at the indexes level of "locations" are combined by using **[&1]** and **[&3]** respectively
- **&2** and **&4** are substituted respectively to denote the key name
  **`"locations"`**

the demo on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ :

[image]

**Edit** (*response for your last edit*):
Considering the input

```json
{
  "data": {
    "distanceUnit": "Mi",
    "solrResponse": {
      "header": {
        "found": 32,
        "retrieved": 10
      },
      "results": [
        {
          "matchScore": "08768",
          "location": {
            "distance": "2.7649",
            "similarity": "0.342"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

you can use the following specs

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "distanceUnit": "=toLower(@(1,&))",
        "solrResponse": {
          "results": {
            "*": {
              "location": {
                "dist1": "=divideAndRound(2,@(1,distance),0.6215)",
                "distanceKm": "=concat(@(1,dist1), ' km')",
                "dist2": "=divideAndRound(2,@(1,distance),1.0)",
                "distanceMiles": "=concat(@(1,dist2), ' km')"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "data": {
        "*": "&1.&",
        "solrResponse": {
          "*": "&2.&1.&",
          "results": {
            "*": {
              "*": "&4.&3.&2[&1].&",
              "location": {
                "@(4,distanceUnit)": {
                  "mi": { "@(2,distanceKm)": "&7.&6.&5[&4].&3.distance" },
                  "km": { "@(2,distanceMiles)": "&7.&6.&5[&4].distance" }
                },
                "similarity": "&5.&4.&3[&2].&Score"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }, 
  {
    "operation": "sort"
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** is :

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but can you please explain why in the first spec you have @(1, ...)  but in the second it is @(2, ...)
Also, service returns an array of location objects. What I need to do to convert distances in all array elements.

Comment: I have updated my question.

Comment: OK @GaryGreenberg , I've updated too.

Comment: Sorry Barbaros it doesn't work

Comment: Barbaros,  what you have posted works but as I said in my question there are about 100 other attributes beside distance and similarity. They need to be returned as is too.
Also, I do need to return only what is inside solrResponse block.
I.e. it all need to be shifted 2 levels up.

Comment: No problem @GaryGreenberg , the piece `"*": "&4.&3.&2[&1].&",` just above location object already represents the attributes other than `similarity`, and `"*": "&2.&1.&"` represents the other content within `solrResponse`  object. Just retry please.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. No attributes of location object except distance showed up in the output. And shifting up didn't work either.  The output shall contain only what is inside solrResponse.